# Why is my data not in order on X axis when plotting on ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a plot on ggplot2 for sleep data. I have all users on x axis and total minutes asleep on y axis, however when I run the function I receive a graph which has the users out of order on the x axis. I will provide an image.

[image: sleepdata graph]

Thanks!

Here is the code I am running

```
ggplot(data=meansleep)+
  geom_point(mapping=aes(x=Id,y=TotalMinutesAsleep, group=1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))
```

Comment: You have to convert the variable user to factor. `forcats::fct_inorder()` would be userful.

Comment: (Those user IDs *are* in order – that variable is of character type, so it’s ordered alphabetically, in which user19 comes before user2.)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the order by changing the Id variable in your data frame to a factor with levels in the order you want.

```
lvls <- as.vector(outer(c("user"), 1:22, paste, sep=""))
meansleep$Id <- factor(meansleep$Id, levels = lvls)
```

Comment: I am receiving same results after creating this new factor..

Comment: Nevermind, I had changed the x value to lvls instead of keeping it at Id, problem solved!

Comment: So if I have all the user_ids already labeled in the correct manner meaning I just want what I have to be organized in chronological order on the X axis how would I do this? I do not want my Id re labeled user1:22, I rather want the labels to stay the same but be in order on the x axis. This is because I have user1:33 however there are missing users within for instance there is only 27 of the 33 users shown on the graph, but I want them listed in chronological order. Thank you!

Comment: In general I prefer names with leading zeros eg user01 etc. This can avoid all sorts of problems.  paste0("user",sprintf("%02d", 1:33))

Comment: @Stackstudent_09 you can always alter the lvls variable to contain only the values you want in your x-axis in the desired order.  Or like mkpt_uk mentions, use a better naming convention to where you don’t have to worry about this at all

Comment: @Mason How would I alter the lvls variable to contain 1:00 - 12:00AM and 1:00-12:00PM if I wanted that on my X Axis instead? Thank you!!

Comment: @Mason it is currently showing up as 1:00:00 AM 1:00:00 PM 10:00:00 AM 10:00:00 PM 11:00:00 AM 11:00:00 PM. etc etc instead of 1 - 11 AM then 1- 10 PM